# How to add an input textbox in PixiJs?

Tags: pixi.js

I'm trying to create a login form and I'm using PixiJs v4 to render everything. It would be ideal to have the login form also in PixiJS as well, instead of using HTML.

How to I create a simple inputbox to capture text?

Comment: Why is it ideal to have the login form also in PixiJS, rather than HTML? I'm just pointing it out, so that you have considered it. There are e.g. games that use both (html for some menus and canvas for game related stuff). That is what I would do normally.

Comment: Yep that's understandable. In my case I'd like to do some animation in which some pixijs sprites sometimes appear over the login box and sometimes under.
If it were separated into the canvas and html on top, then the animation won't quite work as the loginbox is always on top.

Comment: In a few words you should make a sprite with textfield on it, and create HTMLInput which placed out of your scene. Then when sprite tapped you should call focus on HTMLInput to get keyboard (mobile devices), and then modify text in textfield on each key_down event from HTMLInput.
Look how it works in https://github.com/SebastianNette/PIXI.Input (but there is problems in compatibility)

Answer (score 1):

Create your input box in HTML and have 2 canvases; one with a z-index higher than the input box (for sprites that cover the input box), and one with a lower z-index (for sprites that go behind the input box).

```
.higher-canvas {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 99;
}

.lower-canvas {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: -99;
}
```

If you must absolutely have your input element be a part of the stage, have you taken a look at PIXI.Input?  https://github.com/SebastianNette/PIXI.Input

Comment: Unfortunately PIXI.Input is abandoned, but the right way - look how PIXI.Input works and make your own input.

Comment: another interesting library is https://github.com/abraaobuenotype/type